# MongoDB aggregate query result in bactches?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a Collection Posts with schema

```
{
 _id,
 userId,
 name,
 createdAt,
 location,
 teamId
}
```

I want to group the data by userId

```
{
        $match: {
          teamId: new ObjectId(teamId),
          createdAt: { $gte: startTime, $lte: endTime },
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$userId",
          posts: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        },
      },
```

Now I want data in batches of 100, I will loop over 1st batch and perform some action then I have to loop over next batch and so on. How can I do this thing with mongoDb package for nodejs ?

Comment: `$limit` stage or you can set batch size on the aggregate cursor directly. Just to confirm - you're referring to 100 of the grouped end results at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already receiving documents in batches of 1,000: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/bb5fa43ce58f11d4961f1feaa0d6e58ef6bd8378/src/cursor/abstract_cursor.ts#L740

and you can change this number in cursor options at query time https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#aggregate-data-specifying-batch-size

But frankly, it's quite low level. You don't usually need to touch it. The driver takes care of the logistics behind the scene, so that you can use simple top level API https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#asynchronous-iteration  and just iterate the cursor fetching  documents one at a time:

```
for await (const doc of cursor) {
    console.log(doc); // or whatever actions you wanted to do with the document
}
```

it actually loops over the first batch, when it's over it makes `getMore` request to retrieve the next batch: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/bb5fa43ce58f11d4961f1feaa0d6e58ef6bd8378/src/cursor/abstract_cursor.ts#L743 and returns next document to the iterator.